# mod_dav_svn - two virtual hosts for the same repository

Tags: apache-2.4, svn, mod-dav-svn

I use Apache 2 and mod_dav_svn to serve an SVN repository at https://mysite.example.com/svn/

The repository is on disk on the server at /srv/svn/repo1

It works well.

I now want to allow access to *the same repository* via a different host name and with different HTTP authentication.

If I add a separate, additional Apache 2 virtual host for the extra host name and mount the same /srv/svn/repo1 under it, will this work? I can't find a definitive answer on whether this is a supported use of mod_dav_svn, and I'm worried I could experience repository corruption if multiple commits happen simultaneously via those two virtual hosts.

Answer (score 2):

> If I add a separate, additional Apache 2 virtual host for the extra host name and mount the same /srv/svn/repo1 under it, will this work?

Yes

> I'm worried I could experience repository corruption if multiple commits happen simultaneously via those two virtual hosts

Don't worry - technically two commits from different vhosts doesn't differ from 2 parallel commits to single host and the latter work **always**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you able to cite a documentation source for it?

Comment: @DavidNorth - sorry, but - no. It's just IMNSHO